# How do I pass a list from an angular 4 component to html

Tags: angular, angular2-template, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using angular 4  and I want to pass a list to html. 
In angular 4, the component I have is:

```
a = ["abc", "xyz", "lmn"]
```

On the html side:

`<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source='["abc","xyz","lmn"]' placeholder="item..." class="form-control" />`

I have to pass the list in data-source, it's a Bootstrap-3-Typeahead js object.

How do I use it with angular 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind any `attribute` with component `variable` by using `attr` keyword

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" [attr.data-source]="a" placeholder="item..." class="form-control" />
```

Comment: autocomplete is working but why its not storing full value in form.value json, its only storing what i type in input box like "a" from "abc" but after click on autocomplete "abc" word its not storing full "abc" word

Comment: Its depands on the input bindings. Maybe need to bind with input `(change)`   event.

Comment: sorry but how do i implement this?

Comment: Before it had to know what kind of form you are using `model forms` or `reactive forms`. post those implementations, so it can help to indentify the problem

Comment: i am using ```reactive form```